# Memory leak problem related with FastApi, Gunicorn and Multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, async-await, multiprocessing, gunicorn, fastapi

I have encountered a memory leak problem related with Gunicorn FastApi and multiprocessing library.

I have an API with async functions that it is running with gunicorn(
`gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -c app/gunicorn_conf.py app.api.api:application`, where gunicorn_conf.py is a simple configuration file).
This application is used by another batch program that parallelize the processes using python multiprocessing Pool. When the program is running the memory increase and also if I stop the program the memory of the API does not decrease. It continues high.

In such conditions, I encountered a memory leak problem related to the API microservice.  I believe it is related with gunicorn and multiprocessing library. Has anyone encountered the same problem or something similar?

Comment: see https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4649